# Mobile site: On All Questions tab, filter by Unanswered option is not persisted through pagination

Tags: bug

**Steps to reproduce**

1. On any phone, Go to https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/
2. Touch upon "Questions" tab on blue strip on top.
3. Select "Unanswered" in place of "Votes" next to "show" in top right under blue strip.
4. Expected : "Unanswered" should be displayed next to "show"
5. Actual : "Votes" is shown next to "show".

**Test conditions**

- Phone : Pixel 5
- Android 11
- Chrome 94
- Time : 7AM, 02 Oct 2021

**Comments and Side effects**

1. It looks like the issue is with data and not just display. It affects pagination links as well. At the bottom, Link for 2nd page takes to 2nd page sorted by "Votes" instead of filtered by "Unanswered". Link https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions?page=2&sort=Votes&pagesize=50
2. Other options next to "show" like "Newest" or "Active" work fine.
3. Url with filter option as "Unanswered" produces faulty url. Unanswered should not be assigned to Sort parameter. Link https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=Unanswered&pagesize=50
4. This bug does not appear when site is opened in desktop mode (on a laptop).

Comment: Just verified! It's happening on Samsung devices too.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402253/5418136 apparently this bug is stack overflow wide but not well explored.

Comment: It seems that this bug occurs only when responsiveness is turned off. Since mobile browsing is in the process of being deprecated as all the SE sites are being moved over completely to the responsive design, I think it’s unlikely this bug will be fixed. A “solution” would be to simply enable responsiveness by clicking on “full site” in the footer of any page.